# How to create a Alert dialog if there has a return data from previous activity to notify the users?

Tags: android

I'm trying to add alert dialog to my project to notify the users if there has return data from previous activity, however in my approach the if statement has a problem or something missing , even without return data the alert dialog is always pop up any suggestion or idea will be appreciated.

```
//This part is my method
public void dataReceive(){ 
         //requesting data from server
         //adding parameters
         RequestParams params = new RequestParams(); 
         SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
         HashMap<String, String> user = sessionManager.getUserDetails();
        if (user != null) {
            String uid = user.get(SessionManager.USER_ID);
            params.put("user_id", uid);
        }
        try{
            String name = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME);

            username = name;

        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        //This part is my approach 
        Bundle tokens = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if(tokens != null) {
            final PendingRequestPojo pendingRequestPojo = new PendingRequestPojo();
            responseid = tokens.getString("responseid");
            requestid = tokens.getString("requestid");
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "responseid :" + responseid + "\nrequestid : " +
            //requestid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashActivity.this);
            alert.setTitle("ThirdWheel Payment Response");
            alert.setIcon(R.drawable.thinrdwheel_alert);
            alert.setMessage("Your Payment Was Successfull" + " " + username +
                    "Thank you, we Hope you can ride with us Again ");
            alert.setCancelable(true);
            alert.setPositiveButton("Thanks", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    changement();
                    Updatepayment(pendingRequestPojo.getRide_id(), "PAID");
                }
            }).show();

        }  else {

            changement();
        }
    }
```

Comment: just add `token.containsKey("responseid")` to your if condition. so use `if(tokens != null && token.containsKey("responseid"))`

Comment: Hi thank you for response i will try it.

Comment: can you add the Intent part of your previous activity

Comment: Hi @hasan_shaikh the intent where i get the return data is sdk activity class

Comment: From your previous activity your passing some data is it?

Comment: Mr @RajasekaranM M it works now thank you very much for your suggestion and ideas, from PH :)

Comment: Mr @hasan_shaikh yes i pass some data and after fill up some parameters the sdk will give the return data Btw it works thanks for help me out sir :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code has to be as below

```
 public void dataReceive(){ 
         //requesting data from server
         //adding parameters
         RequestParams params = new RequestParams(); 
         SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
         HashMap<String, String> user = sessionManager.getUserDetails();
        if (user != null) {
            String uid = user.get(SessionManager.USER_ID);
            params.put("user_id", uid);
        }
        try{
            String name = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME);

            username = name;

        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        //This part is my approach 
        Bundle tokens = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if(tokens != null && 
tokens.containsKey("responseid") && tokens.containsKey("requestid")) {
            final PendingRequestPojo pendingRequestPojo = new PendingRequestPojo();
            responseid = tokens.getString("responseid");
            requestid = tokens.getString("requestid");
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "responseid :" + responseid + "\nrequestid : " +
            //requestid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashActivity.this);
            alert.setTitle("ThirdWheel Payment Response");
            alert.setIcon(R.drawable.thinrdwheel_alert);
            alert.setMessage("Your Payment Was Successfull" + " " + username +
                    "Thank you, we Hope you can ride with us Again ");
            alert.setCancelable(true);
            alert.setPositiveButton("Thanks", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    changement();
                    Updatepayment(pendingRequestPojo.getRide_id(), "PAID");
                }
            }).show();

        }  else {

            changement();
        }
    }
```